# Determine Empty Text Field via text.isEmpty

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to trigger a modal segue if the text field is empty for which I have following code:

```
@IBAction func createUserButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        if self.emailAddressTextField.text.isEmpty{
            func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
                if (segue.identifier == "ShowErrorSegue"){

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

emailAddressTextField is the text field and what I am trying to learn to do is that user should get a popup if they try to create an account in my app without email address.

The problem is (self.emailAddressTextField.text.isEmpty) doesn't return true even though the text field is empty. What am I missing here?

Please suggest.
Thanks.

Comment: Does that code even compile? You're dumping prepareForSegue in an IBAction which is already a function.

Comment: Are you sure that isEmpty is returning false, or are you assuming that based on the result of the method? You shouldn't be calling prepareForSegue, it's called for you when you perform a segue.

Comment: @KelvinLau, I tried the OP's code, and it does compile -- surprised me. The code makes no sense, but the compiler doesn't complain. The prepareForSegue function is never executed though, even when isEmpty returns true; I guess that's not too surprising.

Comment: @rdelmar, Very interesting. Thanks for testing! I think the fact that Swift functions are first-class citizens is why the compiler doesn't complain. I've seen functions that return a closure... Since functions and closures are essentially identical in the compiler's point of view, I theorize that this is simply a function that produces a closure, but never returned.

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for your reply. I am newbie as you guys can see and really appreciate your help. I was successfully able to raise an alert when field was empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just count your text field elements and you can also get rid of any spaces using stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet method:

```
if countElements(emailAddressTextField.text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(.whitespaceCharacterSet())) > 0 {
    println("not empty")
} else {
     println("empty")
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but i don't understand why my code doesn't work. Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Because you can't declare your function inside your IBAction

Comment: Hi Leonardo - What I am trying to do is when user presses create button I want to validate f certain field are non empty and if they are then give them alert. For which I have done the following:                          @IBAction func createUserButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        if (emailAddressTextField.text.isEmpty) {
            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "No Text"
            alert.message = "Please Enter Text In The Box"
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
            alert.show()
        }
    }